# webstorm не отображает файл .gitignore

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

webstorm не видит файл .gitignore и другие файлы\папки, имя которых начинается с точки. при попытке создать файл .gitignore, появляется сообщение, что файл уже существует.

Answer (score 1):

Файлы, начинающиеся с точки, считаются "скрытыми" (hidden) в файловых системах семейства linux.

Точно так же команда ls без ключа -a не покажет вам эти файлы.

Я почитал переписку на сайте джетбрейнса - рекомендации сводятся к удалению некотрых типов файлов из игнорируемых - см картинку.

Также, там есть клавиатурная комбинация для показа hiiden - файлов, настроить её можно примерно там же, сделав поиск по слову hidden.

[image: Storm]

P.S.

После комментария автора вопроса о том, что эта настройка привела к появлению папки .git но не файла .gitignore - на [сайте](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207051085-Can-t-see-gitignore-files) джета нашлось такое решение  вопроса: надо поставить плагин гитигноре, а потом в этом плагине включить показ игнорируемых файлов:

[image: плагин]

Надеюсь, поможет!

А вообще - идея же заботится о нас, зачем нам открывать гитигнор в проекте? один раз настроил - и забыл...

Comment: а как это можно исправить? в проводнике я настроил их отображение, как сделать, чтобы и webstorm их видел?
Я до этого пользовался manjaro, там все норм настроил, сейчас на ubuntu посадили

Comment: 1)можно вспомнить, в каком месте в WebStorm поставить галочку, чтобы он показывал все файлы. У меня под рукой просто сейчас её нет, может, минут через 20 поставлю. 2)WebStorm поддерживает синхронизацию настроек через их сервер. Но, ВОЗМОЖНО, это работает только при условии официальнйо подписки на него.

Comment: ну вот я тоже ищу эту галочку, все настройки просмотрел, не могу найти. Да и странно, что поиск по настройкам не дает результата

Comment: @Gelloiss - я дополнил ответ, попробуйте так!

Comment: Я так пробовал, удалил все из списка игнора. в итоге папка .git появилась. Но файла .gitignore или папки .idea все равно нет

Comment: @Gelloiss - я еще раз дополнил ответ...